# How to transport a variable from a popup to window while relying on a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, decorator

Consider the following:

1. Window opens a popup
2. Popup contains a javascript function which can be triggered by a button
3. Function takes two predefined arguments and dismisses the popup

This is what the JS looks like

```
<script>
    function dismissPopup(win, myId) {
        // does some stuff I don't want for THIS routine
        win.close();
    }
</script>
```

This is what the popup's HTML looks like

```
<a id="#bar_1" onclick="opener.dismissPopup(window, '1'); return false;">
    now I want this text to be available to window without breaking
    dismissPopup for other implementations
</a>
<a id="#bar_2" onclick="opener.dismissPopup(window, '2'); return false;">
    etcetera
</a>
```

What I have tried (window)

```
var win = window.open(url);
win.focus();

var original_dismissPopup = window.dismissPopup;
window.dismissPopup = function (win, myId) {
    var FOO = $(win.document.body).find('#bar_' + myId).val();
    alert(FOO);
    original_dismissPopup.apply(this, arguments);
};

var X = "I need FOO here"
```

The result is `alert(FOO)` does give me the correct value. However I don't quite understand how to get the variable outside the function's scope.

Also if I comment out the alert the popup is not dismissed at al, it seems my understanding of decorating an existing function is wrong.

Thanks for any guidance.

**UPDATE:**

This seems to solve things, but I think I'm doing something wrong still:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    alert(FOO);
}, 1500);
```